# Add padding-top to scroll when using href="#id"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an anchor tag as follows:

```
<a href="#map_4D85448A3D4C4180A02BD6FC387ABC45" onclick="jumptosection('map_4D85448A3D4C4180A02BD6FC387ABC45');">A Guide</a>
```

It navigates to a section that has the id 'map_4D85448A3D4C4180A02BD6FC387ABC45'. The jumptosection function is as follows:

```
function jumptosection(id) {
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    if(document.all){
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;
    }else{
        var top = 0;
        do {
            top += target.offsetTop  || 0;
            target = target.offsetParent;
        } while(target);

        document.body.scrollTop = top ;
    }
    //$('#article').css.paddingTop = '55px';
    return false;
```

But even if I write nothing in this function, the behaviour is still the same. The problem is that I have a header strip of 92px that hides some part of the section when I click on the given anchor. How do I make it scroll to the given section while adding some pixels to escape the header?

Comment: You haven't shown the important part of your code - the `jumptosection()` function - so I can't give you an example, but you just need to subtract the height of the header strip from the `top` position of the element being jumped to.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The code is no needed for every solution. The problem would be remain if the user disabled js.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible. I would do it without javascript, so it works for all. Even no changes on you JS are needed.

You just need to create an empty element above the element you want to scroll to. The CSS does the magic. It creates a hidden box in the height of you offset:

HTML:

```
<span class="anchor" id="map_4D85448A3D4C4180A02BD6FC387ABC45"></span>
<h1>Element to scroll to</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.anchor {
    display: block;
    height: 92px;
    margin-top: -92px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

See a working demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/eczxm1rs/1/

Answer (score 27):

While the chosen answer serves the purpose, we now have explicit CSS property for this, called `scroll-margin`.

Basically, you avoid any trickery by adding unnecessary elements - this margin is just calculated when you navigate via anchor tag (or if you have set up native css scroll snapping - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts).

Using this with CSS variables is really useful. Here's an example if you have a fixed / sticky header:

```
/* Set the header variable */

--h-header: 50px;

/* Set the scroll margin top on all anchor elements by using .anchor class */
/* Note: I'm setting plus 2.5em so the element has some breathing room on the top */

.anchor {
    scroll-margin-top: calc(var(--h-header) + 2.5em);
}
```

MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin

CSS-Tricks guide: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-margin/

Comment: Great answer! I knew about `scroll-padding-top` (which doesn't work with anchor tags, only `domNode.scrollIntoView()`) but not about `scroll-margin-top`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and fixed it by using **scroll-mt-[100px]** (Tailwind) or **scroll-margin-top: 100px;** (pure css) in the desired element.

In addition, scrolling to an specific element doesn't need a function.
Imagine you want this: onClick of a button, page jumps to a specific element of the page.
simply wrap your button in **`<Link>`** or **`<a>`** tag with the href of #ID_OF_DESIRED_ELEMENT. That's it!